# Symfony2 and doctrine: different encoding between linux and mac

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building a web application using Symfony2.

I noticed a dangerous behaviour when inserting text strings containing special characters into the database, depending on the OS used.

Say for example that the user wants to insert a text field "Cicciò" into a form. If this operation is done on a linux machine the value persisted in the database is correctly "Cicciò".
On the other hand, if the user is a Mac user while typing the same digits the database will store the value "Cicci�".

I am sure this will cause problems in medium-long term.

The server running the application is CentOS based.
I am using MySQL for database and Symfony version is version 2.6.3.

My symfony configuration is

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this kind of discrepancies in the database values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say 'mac user', do you mean an end user using Safari \ Chrome to access your webapp, or a developer running the app under a mac webserver?

Comment: I mean a end user using its browser under MacOS. I explain myself better: if an end user using my application inserts a string in a form containing special characters (for example "Cicciò"), the database will store different values depending on the OS the end user has installed on his local machine. I would like that my web application to be (obviously) OS-independent.

Comment: Chrome in MacOS and Chrome in Windows or Lynux give you different input? I've try this on mac either windows with Chrome and both saved `Cicciò`? Did you try this with another mac?

Comment: How about setting the encoding on the page's meta tag?